# Компиляция Pug (Jade) в PHP через Gulp

Tags: php, html, gulp, jade, pug

Можно ли компилировать `pug` в `php`? Или теперь, чтобы приступить к backend части сайта нужно брать уже скомпилиный `pug` в `html` и переименовать в `php`, а дальше уже работать с ним, и на этом этапе забыть про шаблонизатор, и если в будущем нужно будет что то править то прийдётся все делать уже в этих новых файлах и все преимущества от `pug` пропадают?

Посоветуйте как правильно поступают дальше опытные люди?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для компиляции Pug в PHP-файл используйте [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename):

```
var
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    pug = require('gulp-pug'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename');

// Compiling Pug in HTML
gulp.task('views', function () {
    gulp.src('./views/*.pug')
        .pipe(pug())
        .pipe(rename({
            extname: '.php'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'))
});
```

Сами же функции PHP экранируем через `|` :

```
  h1 FAQ

    .summury
        details
            summary Some text
            p
                | <?php md_cache()?>
```

В итоге код скомпилируется в:

```
   <h1>FAQ</h1>
   <div class="summury">
   <details>
       <summary>Some text</summary>
       <p><?php md_cache()?></p>
   <details>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/pug-php/pug

просто используй вот это.

Логика работы проста:

1. Ты пишешь все свои шаблоны в pug
2. Сайт их постоянно компилирует из pug в html, при надобности кеширует результат
3. Profit!